# Search in Rails with screen shot and meta tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

Here is the case...

In Rails app, you type URL inside text box, and result should comes with, screen shot for that URL page as JPG, few meta tags such as, Title, URL, icon, description, ...or what ever rails can do or I can get.

How this can be done by rails? OR How I can get screen shot for URL???

Detailed answer would be so helpful I'm so new to rails.
Thanks

Comment: Hi - I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Are you asking us for something like the google preview - where any URL the person types will result in an AJAX popup of the HTML page it points to? google probably does that by having visited every single page on the web and storing a screenshot of that page... I'm guessing you'd need to do it on an as-needed basis - yes? Can you fill in the details for us a bit more about what you need?

Comment: @TarynEast. Google preview could be similar.
As i said you have Textbox, you type URL, result in another page should be Screenshot/thumbnail of that URL page with meta tags.
With all of these info provided i should store it in DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IMGKit to generate a thumbnail/screenshot for the particular URL

https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit